# Updating bot's avatar from a url

Tags: python, url, io, discord, discord.py

I'm using discord.py and I just can't seem to update the bot's avatar with an image url. If it's a path it works well. Thus, I'll like some help knowing exactly what is wrong and how to solve it. This is my code. Thanks.

```
    @commands.command(aliases=["edit"], hidden=True)
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def edit_bot_pic(self, ctx, avatar_location):
        valid = validators.url(avatar_location)
        if valid:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(avatar_location) as resp:
                    buffer = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
                    await self.bot.user.edit(avatar=buffer)
        else:
            with open(avatar_location, "rb") as file:
                avatar = file.read()
                await self.bot.user.edit(avatar=avatar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you need to pass a file instead of the buffer for it to work.

```py
buffer = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
file = discord.File(buffer)
await self.bot.user.edit(avatar=file)
```

References:-

- [how do I upload an image](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=bytesio#how-do-i-upload-an-image)

Comment: This is not working though. Edit takes a stream of bytes, so what I'm thinking is that we need to convert the image to bytes. I printed buffer and it gave me <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000219C33AD130>. So I used read() to read the object and it seems like it had so many values. This seems like something that should be easy but is surprisingly hard and annoying.

Comment: does it raise InvalidArgument

Comment: yes. I solved it though. I just removed io.BytesIO and read the bytes straight using await resp.read().

Comment: Great, you can add that as an answer and accept it then.